# Lodash Function

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a lodash function that transforms one plainObject to another plainObject by running each of the first objects values through an iterator and keeping the same keys?

Example:

```
var example = {a: 2}
_.mapObject(example, function(value, key) {return key++}) === {a: 3}
```

Basically I just need an hashtable parallel for calling _.map on an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, it's called [`_.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues).

```
var example = { a: 2 };

_.mapValues(example, function(value) {
  return value + 1;
});
// => { a: 3 }
```